# Error assigning a string array in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am programmatically presenting a view controller and I am changing the value of a string array with a string array value stored in my SQL (gameGAMETABLEDATA).  I am stuck on this error "Cannot assign a value of type 'String' to value of type [String]".   I am not sure why this is happening.  When I println(gameGAMETABLEDATA[index]), I get a string array, but swift is telling me that it is not a string array. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
var gameGAMETABLEDATA: [String] = []


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

            let index = indexPath.row

            //Error below!!! "Cannot assign a value of type 'String' to value of type [String]"
            GameViewController.tableData = gameGAMETABLEDATA[index]

        }
```

println(gameGAMETABLEDATA)[index] returns:

[cricket3.png, cricket1.png, cricket1.png, cricket1.png, cricket1.png, cricket1.png, cricket1.png]

Comment: if tableData is String array and gameGAMETABLEDATA is String array then use direct `resultController.tableData = gameGAMETABLEDATA[index]` or describe more

Comment: Please, add `OnePlayerCricket` class code to question

Comment: Ive updated this and made it simpler to focus on the direct issue.

Comment: What is the output for ` println(gameGAMETABLEDATA[index])` ?

Comment: [cricket3.png, cricket1.png, cricket1.png, cricket1.png, cricket1.png, cricket1.png, cricket1.png]

Comment: its a string array of images from sql database.

Comment: Your tableData is an array and gameGAMETABLEDATA[index] will give a string at index position. Which can not be assigned because both are of not same type.

Comment: Create your array like this. var gameGAMETABLEDATA:[[String]] = []. It will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array declaration seems wrong. Do like below.

```
var gameGAMETABLEDATA: [[String]] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let index = indexPath.row

    //Error below!!! "Cannot assign a value of type 'String' to value of type [String]"
    GameViewController.tableData = gameGAMETABLEDATA[index]

        }
```

Comment: Your gameGAMETABLEDATA should be an Array of array as per your code.

Comment: Did it help you in solving your problem?

Answer (score 0):

`gameGAMETABLEDATA` declared *as array of strings* (e.g. `["game 0", "game 1"]`)
it is ok that `gameGAMETABLEDATA[i]` is `String` (following our example `gameGAMETABLEDATA[0] == "game 0"`)

If you need to show all contents of *Game Table Data* just remove braces in this line:
`GameViewController.tableData = gameGAMETABLEDATA`
If you need some specific data for single game you should use other data structure. Like

```
let gamesData = 
[
 ["title of game 0", "top score of game 0"],
 ["title of game 1", "top score of game 1"]
]
```

This structure is *array of arrays of strings* and particular array of strings can be accessed by `gamesData[0]` — this expression returns `["title of game 0", "top score of game 0"]`

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a single string to your `tableData` property. You can pass the whole array:

```
GameViewController.tableData = gameGAMETABLEDATA
```

wrap the result in square brackets to nest the string in an array:

```
GameViewController.tableData = [gameGAMETABLEDATA[index]]
```

or define your `gameGAMETABLEDATA` property as a matrix:

```
gameGAMETABLEDATA: [[String]]
```